# EF6 update not actually updating the table record?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm having to write a app that effectively copies data from one databaseA.table to databaseB.table but there are a few fields in databaseB that aren't in databaseA.

I've come up with basic code below. The insert works and the update doesn't trow an error, however, the update doesn't actually update any records.

I've confirmed that the bcEmployee object in the update has the new values from databaseA like it should. The employee object is the record from databaseA.

Am I missing something to make this update?

```
BC_employee bcEmployee = new BC_employee();
bcEmployee.emp_id = employee.emp_id;
bcEmployee.emp_firstname = employee.emp_firstname;
bcEmployee.emp_lastname = employee.emp_lastname;

using (BCcontext ctx = new BCcontext())
{
    var existBCemployee = ctx.employee.Find(employee.emp_id);

    if (existBCemployee == null)        //Insert
    {
        //Set default values that aren't in the original database
        bcEmployee.emp_paystat = null;
        bcEmployee.password = null;
        bcEmployee.enroll_date = null;

        ctx.employee.Add(bcEmployee);
    }
    else
    {
        ctx.Entry(existBCemployee).CurrentValues.SetValues(bcEmployee);
    }

    ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Looks like it should work, provided that `CurrentValues.SetValues(bcEmployee)` actually causes changes.

Comment: It really does look fine, unless it's not triggering modified. If you manually do `ctx.Entry(existBCemployee).State = EntityState.Modified` (or whatever) after setting the values does it work?

Comment: Thanks.....looks like I had to manually set the .State = EntityState.Modified.

Comment: Well, no. The change tracker should notice all changes applied by `CurrentValues.SetValues(bcEmployee)`. If it doesn't, either there *are no changes* or maybe you disabled change tracking somewhere. Setting the whole record as modified is overkill.